How to change the intervals of X-axis in matplotlib?
Unemp_data.plot(figsize=(15,6), title = "unemployment rate", lw=1.5)

This is code to plot the unemployment data I got from FRED.  The graph has x interval of 10 years, how do I manipulate it to display intervals of 5 years? And how do I manipulate it to show only a specific interval? (say, from 2014 to 2019)
I tried using plt.xticks([1949, 1959, 1969, 1979, 1989, 1999, 2009, 2019]) but it didn't work.

Difficult to guess. You should add your minimal code. See this

My suspection:The reason why your code failed to change the scale representation is that the core plt code is in the Unemp_data module, which means you should add your code inside the function.
